# How Can I List Which Processes are Using a Specific Disk in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, monitoring

How can I list which process(es) are using a specific disk in Linux?

I'm trying to track down what is writing to my hard drive, because I'd like to move the process's stuff to my SSD so that my hard drive can go into sleep mode.

Comment: I would run `lsof` on the mount point

Comment: +1 for Tshepang, but remember to pipe the output to `more` or to `less`, `lsof` has a nasty tendency to produce an enormous amount of output, :-)

Comment: Actually, the argument of lsof does not have to be the mount point, it can cope with the device filename of the partition well.